# Mime_content in reply email (exchangelib, python)

Tags: python-3.x, exchangelib

First - I use the `exchangelib` package to connect to `EWS` exchange.

I will create a reply to the email as follows:

```py
msg = acc.inbox.all().order_by('-datetime_received')[-1]
mgs.reply_all("Re: Subject", "body of email")
```

But the response created this way doesn't have the mime_content option, which I need to be able to save the email as `.eml` or `.msg`.

The `msg` variable has `mime_content`.

Is there a way to create an email reply with `mime_content`?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`reply_all()` does not return anything. It's just a helper for sending a reply to the email it's called on.

If you want to access the `Message` item that the reply created, you need to search your "Sent" folder for the reply. That message has the `mime_content` field you're looking for.

If you call `msg.create_reply_all(subject, body).send()` instead, then you should get back the ID of the item stored in the "Sent" folder so you don't have to search for it.

Comment: I replied as answer. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make it clear in the comment.

Comment: my next attemp: create new `Message` like reply:

`m = Message(account = acc, 
folder = acc.sent, 
subject = f"Re: {email.subject}", 
body = new_body, 
to_recipients=[Mailbox(email_address=email.sender.email_address)]
)`

but `m` has mime_contente `None`